# Error on expecting key word

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting error on expecting key word

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

  if Rails.env.development?
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  else
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg",
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
                :storage => :dropbox,
                :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
                :path => ":style/:id_filename"
  end


  validates :name, :description, :price, :address, :phone, presence: true 
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0}
  validates :phone, length: { maximum: 14 }

  validates_attachment_presence :image
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Please fix formatting of the question.   Also, post the stack trace and call out the exact line where you're getting the error.

Comment: Please paste your error message in your original post.

Comment: As already suggested, edit your question to include the exact and full error message you see.

Comment: Hey @kim could you please format your code and post the error log as well. It would help us to understand your problem. BTW welcome to Stackoverflow. Feel free to ask genuine questions

Comment: thank you help .its working now  but the image is not uploading in dropbox

Answer (score 1):

Extra comma at the end of line

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg",
```

without a comma at the end of line

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Hope this might help you .....

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

  if Rails.env.development?
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:medium => "200", :thumb => "100x100>"}, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  else
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:medium => "200", :thumb => "100x100>"}, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/,
                                      :storage => :dropbox, :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"), :path => ":style/:id_filename"

  end

  validates :name, :description, :price, :address, :phone, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than: 0}
  validates :phone, length: {maximum: 14}

  validates_attachment_presence :image
  belongs_to :user

end
```